# Access a control's Text property after parent form Dispose()'d?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Long-time joelonsoftware follower, 1st-time stackoverflow poster.

I want to know "how safely" I can do the following (C#):

```
Form formDlg = new Form();
TextBox box = new TextBox();
formDlg.Controls.Add( box );
formDlg.ShowDialog();
formDlg.Dispose();
string sUserEntered = box.Text; // After parent Dispose'd!
```

In practice, this (apparently) works, because **box** (as a **Control**) has a private **text** field (a string) which it uses to implement its Text property after its window handle is destroyed.

I won't be satisfied by a general answer that "you can't access an object after it's Disposed" because (1) I can't find any such blanket prohibition in MS docs, (2) I'm not accessing an unmanaged resource, and (3) this code doesn't throw any exception (including ObjectDisposedException).

I would like to do this so I can create and use a combined "ShowAndDispose" method to reduce the risk of forgetting to always call Dispose() after ShowDialog().

To complicate, the behavior changes in the debugger. If I break before Dispose(); then Quick Watch **box** and drill down into its **Control** base class; then step past Dispose(); then box.Text returns ""! In other scenarios box.Text returns the user-entered text.

Comment: Why would you force a Dispose on the Form? Especially when you're not accessing unmanaged resources. Let the framework/GC take care of it. EDIT: I have this feeling that you have a far more complicated situation than the code above.

Comment: Not alone that, why access a textbox that is on a form that is dispose()...? why would you want to do that? Doesn't make sense to me? That's like pointers in C, you malloc a pointer, do some stuff with it, then free it, then dereference the pointer after being free'd!

Comment: Zyphrax: A Form holds many unmanaged resources, 1 per Control.

Comment: @Henk: true, but I see no use to manually Dispose the class. His form isn't a class variable (as far as I can tell). Eventually it will lose any active references and will be disposed automatically by it's destructor Dispose call.

Comment: Zyphrax: That is true for all IDisposable objects but we have the disposable pattern, IDisposable interface and using clause because we _should_ always clean up ourselves. The GC is very inefficient and unpredictable.

Comment: @Zyphrax: Check your ShowDialog() doc, you are supposed to call Dispose(), not wait for GC. Dtors can wait a long time to get called.
@tommieb75: The whole point of this ? is that it's not clear to me that a Dispose'd control is "like a freed pointer".

Comment: @Zyphrax: I meant my specific "box.Text" call is "not accessing unmanaged resources", since the box object has cached the text. Creating the dialog does of course use unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Henk: I don't agree with the `always clean up` part. It makes sense to clean up certain classes (with active handles or connections): SqlConnection, Streams etc. However many classes inherit the IDisposable pattern from another class, where it does simply nothing. Another risk of manually disposing, is that you have to be absolutely sure that the instance isn't going to be used by any code in your application (something that the GC detects for you). E.g. there are many SharePoint (and some WCF) classes that you should NOT manually dispose because it causes unpredictable results.

Comment: @Conrad: Yeah, I read in the doc that ShowDialog simply doesn't close your form but hides it after the user closes the dialog. Therefor the reference isn't automatically cleaned up. I don't know if the Close method calls Dispose, but that would make more sense to me (with many classes it does).

Comment: @Zyphrax: Of course there are exceptional situations and broken classes where we don't (cannot) clean up deterministically. But you are turning that into complete surrender by _never_ disposing Forms and other Disposables.

Comment: Even though I think it is really unnecessary to do what you are proposing, you get a +1 because this is a good question that should stimulate some decent discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an implementation detail that this code runs without a problem.  The Control.Text property happens to be cached by the Control class so disposing the TextBox doesn't cause an ObjectDisposed exception.

That's fairly rare btw, lots of control property getters and setters generate a Windows message to ask the native Window control for the property value.  You'll get a kaboom on those because the Handle property is no longer valid.  Notable also is that the Text property setter updates the cached value but also generates a Window message to update the native control.  Kaboom here.

I assume this is just general interest, don't ever use code like that in your program.  Well, you'd find out quick enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'using' statement to ensure an object gets disposed when you're done with it:

```
using(Form frmDialog = new Form())
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

frmDialog will get disposed once the block has run I believe.

Comment: Doesn't really change his question. In comparison the `string sUserEntered = box.Text;` would come after the using block.

Comment: Yes, that is a better cure than a ShowAndDispose() method.

Comment: @Zyphrax, no, it would solve the OP's problem about forgetting Dispose and of course the box.Text code would go inside the using.

Comment: Thx but I think using is ugly, & if I remember to use using I can just as easily remember to call Dispose().

Comment: @Conrad: get used to `using`, everybody does. And you get a try/finally for free.

Comment: @Conrad: do use `using` if you can, it's far nicer than those try finally blocks. @Henk: Then why isn't the `string sUserEntered = box.Text;` called before the `formDlg.Dispose` line. In comparison with the example in the question, it would come after the using block (to do exactly the same). - I'm not saying it makes sense though ;)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger scenario makes me think that what you do is not reliable, to test it you should at least try this:

```
formDlg.Dispose();
Application.DoEvents();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();   
string sUserEntered = box.Text; // After parent Dispose'd!
```

Comment: OK I tried that, it still "works". The formDlg and box variables are still in scope so I wouldn't expect GC to affect their objects. Thx anyway.

Comment: @Conrad: I'm still doubtful, why would the text disappear in the debugger?

Comment: I did some testing and the text does disappear with all the variations I tried. Until I placed the text value from the control into a public property, I wasn't able to get the text value back to my main form - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I put the `sUserEntered` value into a public property so it could be accessed:

```
    public string UserInput
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public frmDialog()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserInput = userInput.Text;
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Then in my mainform:

```
        using (dialog = new frmDialog())
        {
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            stringUserInput.Text = dialog.UserInput;
        };
```

Comment: Thx, I know I can do that, creating a whole new class is a lot more extra code than I want.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me, I can create & use a Form-derived class with a BeginShowDialog() method which calls ShowDialog(), and an EndShowDialog() method which calls Dispose(). The "Begin" in the method name will make the need for the "End" call more obvious.

I miss C++'s determinate destruction of locals on leaving scope.

Comment: You'd still have to wrap it in a try/finally block, so the gain over using is debatable.

Comment: I'll skip the try/finally. In the never-happens-in-the-real-world case that ShowDialog() throws, I'll live with the resource leak.

Comment: I disagree that "using" "solves" the problem I want to address, which is never forgetting, for the hundreds of classes I use, when/whether each one needs to be disposed. If I don't remember that, then I won't remember to use "using" for that class any better than I'll remember to call Dispose().

Comment: Yes, the way I reuse my own code, if I had a ModalDialog class which hid ShowDialog() then I think I'd use it. But honestly, after spending this much time discussing Dispose() it'll probably be a long time before i forget it again. ;)